# Need to program Ajax Ctrol Tlkt AutoCompleteExtender with "similar" results as well

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've got the Ajax AutoCompleteExtender up, running, working and so forth with a webservice to return my result from SQL.

What I would like to do now is allow the user the ability to get similar results, if they cant remember the exact name of the term they are looking for.

For example, they may intend to get "Marriott - Omaha" but the only part the can remember is "Omaha". So far, they only way I can get the completed prefix is to begin typing from the exact beginning of the prefix.

I'm wondering if this can be done by changing my query or just adding a javascript to work with the extender.

To specific, I'm looking for functions similar to [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/).

**Here is my current AutoCompleteExtender..**

```
                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                ID="ClientSearchAC"
                runat="server"
                BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
                TargetControlID="ClientSearch"
                ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx"
                ServiceMethod="GetClients"
                MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                CompletionInterval="20"
                EnableCaching="true"
                CompletionSetCount="50"
                CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
                CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
                CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
                OnClientPopulating="suggestionListPopulating"
                OnClientPopulated="suggestionListPopulated"
                OnClientHidden="suggestionListPopulated" />
```

**Here is my web service Method**

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetClients(string prefixText)
{
    SqlCeConnection sqlCon = new SqlCeConnection();
    sqlCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    DataSet dtst = new DataSet();
    string strSql = "SELECT Name FROM [Current] WHERE Name LIKE '" + prefixText + "%' ";
    SqlCeCommand sqlComd = new SqlCeCommand(strSql, sqlCon);
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCeDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand = sqlComd;
    sqlAdpt.Fill(dtst);
    string[] cltName = new string[dtst.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow rdr in dtst.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            cltName.SetValue(rdr["Name"].ToString(), i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
    return cltName;
}
```

**Finally, here are existing js functions I have added to display an Ajax type loading image during the search**

```
  function suggestionListPopulating(source, e) {
      var textboxControl = $(source.get_element()); // Get the textbox control.
      textboxControl.css('background', '#FFF url(/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat right');       // Put ajax loader image in while search queries results.
  }

  function suggestionListPopulated(source, e) {
      var textboxControl = $(source.get_element()); // Get the textbox control.
      textboxControl.css('background', '#FFF url(/images/search.png) no-repeat 4px 4px');       // Remove ajax loader image and return textbox to normal style manually.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I may have found the answer to my own question here.

[Autocomplete extender in Ajax Toolkit and JQuery limiting to “Starts with”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139457/autocomplete-extender-in-ajax-toolkit-and-jquery-limiting-to-starts-with)

I just needed to change my web method in order to get "Similar" results as well.
The AutoCompleteExtender is limited in its default functionality so we have to specify how we want to return data within the web method.